# How to attach event handler to a list item template?

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to create a template using `sap.m.ColumnListItem`.

Any thing wrong in the template? If I remove the `press` handler, binding works. But I want an event handler to be attached to the list items.

Below is the code:

```js
var oItemTemplate = new ColumnListItem({
    type: "Navigation",
    press: this.handleItemPress,
    cells: [/*...*/],
});
```

Comment: You should assign an **array** to that `press` event with the function as the first and `this` as the last element. See the *Example 2* in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61603539/5846045

Answer (score -1):

There is one issue I noticed with the template. The lisTtype should be an "enum" and not "string" as mentioned "Navigation" in your case.

You can use it like **type : sap.m.ListType.Navigation,**

For more information on listTypes : https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListType

Also, I tried a similar to do the same and worked for me here: http://veui5infra.dhcp.wdf.sap.corp:8080/snippix/#12852

Best Regards,
Nandan

Comment: Thank you Nandan. 
type: "Navigation" is not a problem here. I am getting the output only if I remove Press.

Comment: Hi Chethan, do you get an error like "this.handleItemPress" is not a function?
If so, could you try defining the function inline itself i.e.
press:function(){
handle the code here.
}

Comment: The code just comes put without even creating the template. It does not error out for "this.handleItemPress".
I have used a different model , I am refreshing the model rather than binding everytime

Comment: Hi Chethan, can you please share the complete relevant code?

Comment: Hi chethan, what is the mode of the list ? Can you also add that piece of code also in the question?

Answer (score -1):

Before your code, add : `var that = this;`

Then change with : `press: that.handleItemPress,`