# How to properly attach and detach event handler in UI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have problems with data binding of my custom control.

My control inherits from `sap.m.Input` and extends it with a special value helper. One of my new properties of my new control is a simple header for the value help dialog. This is bound to an i18n model.

When I now use my control in a normal form, everything works. The title is bound correctly and shows the value of the bound i18n property in that model. If I use my control as a template in a column of a `sap.ui.table` control, it only shows the default value of the title property. Data binding does not seem to work. But is still working on the inherited properties (such as value).

For simplification here my control which now has only that title property and if value help is requested, it shows the current value in an alert box. In table, it shows the default value. And without table, it shows the bound value from i18n model.

Here the simplified control code:

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/Control",
  "sap/m/Input",
], function(Control, Input) {
  "use strict";

  return Input.extend("DvpClsSuggestInput", {
    "metadata": {
        "properties": {
          // Title of Value-Help Dialog
          "vhTitle": {
            type: "string",
            defaultValue: "Title"
          }
        }
      },
    
      init: function() {
        Input.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
        this.setShowValueHelp(true);
        this.attachValueHelpRequest(this.onValueHelpRequest.bind(this));
      },
    
      onValueHelpRequest: function(oEvent) {
        var lvTitle = this.getVhTitle();
        alert(lvTitle);
      },

    });
  });
});
```

Usage in `sap.ui.table.Table` (which doesn't work and shows the default value of the title property):

```xml
<table:Column>
  <m:Label text="{i18gn>HausWaehrung}" />
  <table:template>
    <dvp:MyInput
      value="{ path: 'Inv>Hwaer', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.String' }"
      vhTitle="{i18n>Currency}" />
  </table:template>
</table:column>
```

Usage which works:

```xml
<VBox>
  <dvp:MyInput
    value="{ path: 'Cls>/Currency', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.String' }"
    vhTitle="{i18n>Currency}" />
</VBox>
```

Once again, binding against the value property works in both ways. Problem only exists with my own property `vhTitle`. Any Ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do NOT use `.bind` when attaching event handlers** to `ManagedObject`'s events. The same applies to detaching event handlers. UI5 has its own documented mechanism for passing listener objects for those cases.

### Example 1

[Attaching](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.Input#methods/attachValueHelpRequest) / [detaching](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.Input#methods/detachValueHelpRequest) a `valueHelpRequest`-handler using the corresponding APIs and passing values to the list of arguments **as documented** in the API reference:

```js
myInput.attachValueHelpRequest(/*obj?,*/this.onValueHelpRequest, this); // No .bind!
myInput.detachValueHelpRequest(this.onValueHelpRequest, this); // Same references
```

### Example 2

Attaching an event handler on control instantiation **as documented** in [`ManagedObject`'s API reference](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject#constructor) (All controls are ManagedObjects):

```js
new MyInput({
  // ...,
  valueHelpRequest: [/*obj?,*/this.onValueHelpRequest, this]
});
```

> ##### Valid Names and Value Ranges:
>
> - [...]
> - For events, either a function (event handler) is accepted or an **array** of length 2 where the first element is a function and the 2nd element is an object to invoke the method on; or an array of length 3, where the first element is an arbitrary payload object, the second one is a function and the 3rd one is an object to invoke the method on [...].

### Example 3 (For control developers)

In **control definition**, however, the listener can be omitted completely because the event provider itself (i.e. your control instance) becomes the listener by default if no listener object is passed.

```js
this.attachValueHelpRequest(this.onValueHelpRequest); // the control instance will be used as the context in that event handler
```

This is described in the [API reference](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.base.EventProvider#methods/attachEvent) as well:

> If *<oListener>* is not specified, the handler function is called in the context of the event provider.

### Drawbacks of using [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) in UI5

1. When calling `.bind` on a function, an entire **new** function is created!

   ```js
   const myFn = function() {};
   myFn === myFn.bind(); // returns: false
   ```

   Meaning if a handler is passed with `.bind`, that **handler becomes never detachable** because `detachEvent` awaits the same function reference and the same listener object reference as when `attachEvent` was called.
2. To make things worse, the function created with `.bind` won't let you change the previously passed *thisArg* (`this`) even if the [`EventProvider` tries to `call`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/113fa277834dba5c5acaffa3680181a5d97a1c79/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/EventProvider.js#L245) the function afterwards with a different *thisArg*. This limitation is described in the [ECMAScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function.prototype.call) (See Note 2), and also the cause of the issue described in the question. When `ManagedObject` clones the `template` control for aggregation binding, the listener cannot be overwritten!